# (USA) Can reproduction of a public record be prohibited?

Tags: united-states, personal-information, freedom-of-information

Partial image of what I suspect is a public record:[image]

**Is "reproduction prohibited" legally enforceable?**  That would make thousands of genealogists in violation, as well as sites like FamilySearch.org and Ancestry.com.

I'm not asking about the privacy aspect—I realize most jurisdictions have privacy protections on such documents.  But it seems to me that anyone obtaining such a document **legally** has the right to provide it to others for the information it contains.  And I realize that if it is presented with the purpose of obtaining something that the provider of something doesn't have to accept it.  Merely asking about the general prohibition.

Related: [Find out if "Further reproduction prohibited without permission" document is original](https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/79961/find-out-if-further-reproduction-prohibited-without-permission-document-is-ori) but that concerns items actually copyrighted.

Answer (score 0):

This depends on the law of the particular state, but such a law applicable to vital records does exist. It is against the law in Washington under [RCW 70.58A.060](https://app.leg.wa.gov/rcw/default.aspx?cite=70.58A&full=true) to

> prepare or issue any vital record that purports to be an original,
> certification of, or copy of a vital record except as authorized in
> this chapter.

The chapter does not sanction making a photocopy. However, the state registrar can permit copying, and as a matter of course does so for records of a certain age which is how Family Search gets access to old birth certificates (it does also include user uploading illegal copies). The websites don't make copies, as far as I know, they distribute already-copied records which may have been created legally or illegally. I do not know if anyone has been prosecuted for good-faith copying of a record – the law is there to give legal leverage against identity fraud.

Comment: I'm pretty skeptical about the constitutionality of laws like this in the absence of ill-intent. This may be why the law is enforced relatively leniently.

Comment: Yes, OP seems to be assuming such rules exist and inquiring whether they are valid.

Comment: RCW 70.58A.520(6) might cover the genealogical websites.  And the required written agreement may cover the release for genealogical purposes.  But I still have my doubts about the enforceability of New York's "reproduction prohibited" on a public record given to a relative or a record old enough to not have privacy restrictions.

Comment: It's not just identity fraud; the issue is that the original birth certificate may be sealed in the case of adoption (RCW 70.58A.400). The idea of prohibiting outside copies is to prevent, for example, a site keeping and distributing now-sealed documents.

Comment: @ohwilleke in many countries, copying classified or otherwise protected documents requires no ill intent. For classified documents a lot of that is true in the US too.

Comment: @Trish But these are "public documents" in the sense of being available to the public.

Comment: @ohwilleke *are* they? OP claims that, but does not actually state what they are, and why they would. The state makes **many** non public documents, or documents that are protected specially.